# Will Django channels good for to use asynchronous long running background functionality

Tags: python, django, django-views

While working on request where i need to do long running bulk operation on backend ( which takes almost 15-30 min now) for each individual user to avoid load on database. I see Django channel with Redis as channel layer can helps to achieve this. Will that be good fit to do this as asynchronous long running job separately using Django channels. I saw mostly its used for real time communication not sure will that used for my purpose also. Please suggest thoughts will that be right approach or any other option should i use to perform long running background functionality while using Django.

No option tried just explored django channel

Comment: I've used django-channels for one of my project, which looks for incoming files, and send to some printers.  I believe for long running background  tasks django-celery,  DjangoQ  or python-rq  is fine

Comment: https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/django/first-steps-with-django.html
https://django-q.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
https://python-rq.org/